IntelliJ form doesn't bind to my JPanel class
I am making a multiple page application with Swing where the pages are different JPanels that I add to a blank panel. I have made the designs of the pages using IntelliJ's UI editor, but when I create the page JPanel and add it to the application's blank panel it shows empty. I don't know much about how Swing works so I might be missing something. Do I have to add something to the constructor?
Here is my JPanel class
public class MenuPage extends JPanel
{
   private JPanel menuPanel;
   private JButton btn_AddNew;
   private JButton btn_Pizzas;
   private JButton btn_Drinks;
   private JButton btn_Sauces;
   private JButton btn_Desserts;
   private JButton btn_Vegan;

   public MenuPage()
   {
       super();
       System.out.println("menu added");
   }
}

And this is how it's supposed to look like, but instead I get a white box


The code you posted doesn't instantiate the components (menuPanel and buttons), nor adds them to the MenuPage, nor sets the proper LayoutManagers, nor customizes the colors and borders. It just declares that these components can be referenced from the code. It is a good idea to learn Swing without the use of visual editors, since this will enable you to fully exploit the framework's capabilities and will let you understand, customize and fix missing things. This also requires Java coding knowledge too of course.

There are plenty of resources online for learning Swing, such as the Oracle's Swing tutorials.
